# How to select text in editor using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, end-to-end

I am tester and beginer in Cypress.
I have a editor and typing it any text.
After typing I want to select my typing text and do with it anything /ex. change a style/

this is my html code

```
<div class="editor">
    <p> my text </p>
</div>
```

Does anyone have a way on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set type to `{selectall}` - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Week-Inputs

```
cy.get('.editor').type('{selectall}');
```